# Unicode surrogates and combinig characters

Tags: unicode, utf-16, surrogate-pairs

I'm thinking about using UTF-16 in an application. But I have some difficulties in understanding some key concepts.
In particular the surrogates and combinig characters.

As I understand the surrogates are used for UTF-16 to allow encoding of codepoints that need more than 16 bits.
So if I use surrogates my UTF-16 character needs 32 bits.

Combining characters allow alternative form for compability reasons to older encodings. So for example I can write the character `ä` also as `a` followed by `¨`.

- `ä`: U+00E4
- `a`: U+0061
- `◌̈`:U+0308 (Combining diaeresis)

So if I use surrogates together with combinig characters it can happen, that my character needs 2 x 32 bits for encoding. This doesn't happen for my example of course. Since there are no surrogates involved. But could it happen with other characters?

Comment: A glyph can be built from any number of combining characters, google "zalgo" for extreme examples.  So the notion that you can store a glyph in 32 bits is already invalid.  It is not a problem if you simply only consider storing coding units.  The wonky stuff is for the text rendering engine to sort out.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know that it's possible to build a glyph from more than two combining characters. But it makes sense even thou most possible combinations don't make sense from a linguistics point of view.